# Android Notepad3 run-time error forece close

Tags: android

When I run the Notepad3 tutorial, I got this error message:

> The application
>   com.android.demo.notepad3 (process
>   com.android.demo.notepad3) has stopped
>   unexpectedly

It force close. What's wrong?

Comment: What does the LogCat say?  A "Force Close" is triggered by an uncaught exception

Comment: To examine LogCat, use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse. You are looking for a stack trace associated with the exception.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for adding that, I should have done that myself

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Per your suggestion, checked LogCat I found: 09-06 18:01:10.292: WARN/dalvikvm(279): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-06 18:01:10.312: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 18:01:10.312: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android.demo.notepad3/com.android.demo.notepad3.Notepadv3}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you give us the full stack trace?  Edit your question to avoid hitting the 600 character limit.